# Is it possible to write an excel file with multiple sheet and insert a named table in each sheet?

Tags: r, excel, datatables, excel-tables

I usually generate a new excel file with multiple sheet in this way, using the write.xlsx function and insert in it a list of database each one with an own name:

```
#EXAMPLE:
[....]
list_of_datasets <- (list("MARCO" = dtMarco, "LUCA" = dtLuca, "GIACOMO" = dtGiacomo)) # with this i give sheetnames 
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets, "G:/GENCARELLI/MACCHINE.xlsx")
```

it actually work well but my next step is to open the excel and create a named table for each worksheet.
I already given different name to the single sheets but i need to know if i can create in R with some command already files with named table.

I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a loop. This is a reproducible example where the named range for the data is the same as the data and sheet name:

```
library(openxlsx)

list_of_datasets <- list("MARCO" = mtcars, "LUCA" = iris, "GIACOMO" = anscombe)


# create a workbook

wb <- createWorkbook()

for(i in seq_along(list_of_datasets)){

  #create worksheets for each data set
  addWorksheet(wb, names(list_of_datasets)[i])
  
  #write and name data for each worksheet
  writeData(wb, 
            sheet = names(list_of_datasets)[i],
            x = list_of_datasets[[i]], 
            name = names(list_of_datasets)[i])  
  
}




saveWorkbook(wb, "example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method presented by @Peter is to use `purrr::iwalk()`. First you capture the steps in a function:

```
add_new_data <- function(dataset, name) {
  #create worksheets for each data set
  addWorksheet(wb, name)
  
  #write and name data for each worksheet
  writeData(wb, 
            sheet = name,
            x = dataset, 
            name = name)  
}
```

and then after running the following:

```
library(openxlsx)

list_of_datasets <- list("MARCO" = mtcars, "LUCA" = iris, "GIACOMO" = anscombe)

wb <- createWorkbook()
```

iterate through each using `iwalk()`:

```
purrr::iwalk(list_of_datasets, add_new_data)
```